# DataTables - sorting, searching, pagination not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables plugin.
Data is populated, but pagination, searching and sorting not working. My jQuery version  is 3.5.1 , DataTables version is 1.10.24, I have all tbody,tr,th,td tags.
Link to Datatables.js is in html, link to datatables css is in head. My table id is #mytable- the same as in DataTables script.
What's wrong?

My code:
*user.php*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="lt">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
    <body>
    <?php 
    $menu = 3;
    require '../layout/nav.php';
    ?>
    <caption><h2 class="text-center">Users</h2></caption>
    <?php
    require '../db/db.php'; // Connect to the database.
    $query="SELECT id,name FROM user"; 
    $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    echo '
    <table id="mytable" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">name</th>
    </tr></thead>';
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $id=htmlspecialchars($row['id'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $name=htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
    echo '<tbody><tr>
    <td>'.$id.'</td>
    <td>'.$name.'</td>
    </tr></tbody>';
    }
    echo '</table>'; 
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#mytable').DataTable();
    } );
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the tbody around the loop instead of putting it inside.

```
<table>
  <thead>
   ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr> <!-- row 1-->
    <td>
    <td>
   </tr>
   <tr> <!-- row 2-->
    <td>
    <td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```